# My bike bike Suzuki Fiero (2001 Model) missing and jumping, reducing power when riding in rain

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, power-loss

My bike bike Suzuki Fiero (2001 Model) missing and jumping, reducing power when riding in rain.
As per the instruction from Mechanic i changed the following ...

Changed Spark Plug and adapter
Cleaned Carburetor
Checked ignition switch
changed the regulate

Still i am facing the problem, please Suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the sparkplug cable - age makes them susceptible to moisture ingress causing loss of spark. You may see stray sparks when it is dark...

Comment: If you're bike has a conventional distributor, the distributor cap is also subject to age- and heat-related cracking. The cracks may be too small to see, and can definitely yield bad running in damp conditions.